# Plugin interfaces in fortran

Tags: plugins, hook, fortran

This is a weird question, considering the implementation language, but still.

There is a program, written in Fortran 95. I want to make some parts of it customizable, using some kind of plugins and hooks. There is a limitation though: this has to be done purely in Fortran, no resort to C or any other language, and preferably (but not strictly required) still Fortran 95, no 2003 features. Think of extension module to be something like

```
module some_extension
  use main_module, only: register_hook
  use public_interface_module

  subroutine init()
    call register_hook(my_hook)
  end subroutine init

  subroutine my_hook()
    ...
  end subroutine my_hook
end module some_extension
```

I don't think I'm the first one who wants to make an extendable program in Fortran. Is there a common practice for doing such things? Not necessary literally this kind of interface, but something close in spirit.

Comment: Wouldn't function pointers serve your need? This: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/285/how-to-work-with-function-pointers-in-fortran-in-scientific-programs might be interesting for you. This too: http://www.macresearch.org/advanced_fortran_90_callbacks_with_the_transfer_function

Comment: @haraldkl, Procedure pointers (which are very different from passing procedure as an argument to another procedure) are part of Fortran 2003 only, and according to [Fortran wiki](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Fortran+2003+status) are not supported by some high profile Fortran compilers. It is a strict requirement for my code to be as compatible as possible, and even resorting to external C code looks better in this case...

Comment: Of course, if you try and do this via C and Fortran 95, then you bring in a whole heap of potential incompatibilities.  If you use C via the C interop facilities of F2003, then ... you are using F2003.

Comment: A more recent version of the Fortran 2003 compiler compliance table -- http://www.fortranplus.co.uk/resources/compiler_table_revision_9.pdf -- indicates that the Absoft, Oracle (formerly Sun) and Pathscale compilers are now the only ones which don't implement procedure pointers.

Comment: Actually the link by abbot to the fortranwiki says the same. Abbot: though procedure pointers were only standardized in F2003, it is still possible to use this functionality in F95, please have a look at the macresearch link I posted above. It is using transfer for varying arguments, which isn't really nice, but it still might give you some ideas. Anyway, I'd consider the compilers which do not support procedure pointers yet as pretty much unmaintained.